# What is the difference between AR and VAR?

Tags: regression, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

**What is the exact difference between an autoregressive (AR) and vector autoregressive model (VAR)?**

I always thought that VAR would just be for more than two variables, until I learned that AR can also have more than two variables. I.e. I had a misunderstanding(?) that AR models are not always bivariate.

Before I write too much potentially false assumptions about the difference between AR and VAR, it would rather be interested to see if anyone can make provide a quick and good summary.

Comment: Isn't a VAR simply an AR with vectors?

Answer (score 3):

I think we can distinguish these types of models:

- [Simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression): one equation, two variables: $y_i=\alpha+\beta x_i + \epsilon_i, \; i=1:N$
- [Multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_regression): one equation, more than two varibles: $y_i=\alpha+\beta_1 x_{1i}+...+\beta_I x_{pi}+ \epsilon_i, \; i=1:N$
- [Multivariate Linear model or General linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model): More than one equation, apparently more than one variable.
- Nonlinear version of preceding models.

We can conclude that:

- AR(1) is a simple linear regression because it is linear in parameters, has one variable and one equation. Please note that $y_t$ is different from $y_{t-1}$, although we might assume stationarity or etc.
- AR(p) for p>1 is in fact a multiple linear regression model, because it has one equation and more than one variables ($y_t,\; y_{t-1},\; ...,\; y_{t-p}$). It might have other exogenous variables.
- VAR(p) model is a multivariate linear regression model. It has more than one equation and variable. It might also have different exogenous variables.

I am open to comments.

Answer (score 2):

VAR (vector autoregression) is a generalization of AR (autoregressive model) for multiple time series, identifying the linear relationship between them. The AR can be seen as a particular case of VAR for only one serie.

The hypothesis necessary to apply the VAR is the series is just that one influence other in a intertemporal way.

About AR with more than one serie, you may have seen something like AR models of different series that have any relationship between them, as for example [simultaneous equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model), where there is some equilibrium condition.